# Oracle SQL - Count XML nodes in a clob type column

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, count, clob

I was trying to write an optimized SQL query to count a specific XML node in clob type column, for now I'm using a REGEXP_COUNT to browse through all rows and all XMLs, but this is terribly slow.

Like this:

```
SELECT sum(REGEXP_COUNT(clobtype_column_withXMLs, '/Node_Closing_tag', 1)) as 'Node_number' FROM MY_TABLE;
```

This works, but with hundreds of millions of tags it takes literally ages.

I want to bypass the XML structure and shorten the count time. I have found some things, but most of them involve changing the column type to xml and use xquery and other DML functions.
In my case I can't modify the table, I only need the number, how many times the specified node occurs in the column.

My table structure:

not an XML Table, various column types and a `CLOB type column`, in which every row contains a different sized XML (hundreds of millions of characters).
The XML has pretty complex structure, the one node I'm searching for is in the middle:

```
1/2/3/4/5/I'm_searching_for_this/contains_multiple_nodes
```

Is there any fast way to count nodes in a structure like this, without modifying anything in the table? With fast I mean, **count 500 million nodes in a couple of hours maximum**. (text search takes 24h+)

Comment: `" I have found some things, but most of them involve changing the column type to xml and use xquery and other DML functions."` So you find your answer

Comment: "In my case I can't modify the table"

Comment: You don't have to change the column type in the table to use XQuery. You'd have to experiment to see if on-the-fly conversion, extraction and counting is any faster than what you're doing now though.

Comment: Also does the node you're searching for always have open and close tags - you'd never have a self-closing empty node like `<targetNodeName />` ?

Comment: yes it does always have and open and close tag, my count query gave very accurate numbers, but sometimes it lasted 12+ hours, in my upcoming cases the data will be doubled, that's why I'm looking for a faster solution

Comment: I've tried Xquery and it responded with a the wrong column type error, that's why I came to the conclusion that its not feasible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *replace and measure length difference* trick shoudl work for you with the same result as the `REGEXP_COUNT` (not necessary on the same precision when you *parse XML* and counts elements, which should have the ultimate precision).

The advantage of the `REPLACE` approach is that it will be the fastest implementation.

Simple

- replace each occurence of the searched substring in the original string with `NULL`
- calculate the difference of length of the original string and the replaced one
- divide the result with the length of the substring to get the result count

.

```
select 
 sum(REGEXP_COUNT(clobtype_column_withXMLs, '/Node_Closing_tag', 1)) cnt1,
 sum( (length(clobtype_column_withXMLs) - length(replace(clobtype_column_withXMLs,'/Node_Closing_tag',null)))  / length('/Node_Closing_tag')) cnt2
from tst
```

I'd recomend to perform some test using different search substrings

```
 /tag
 tag/
 <tag>
 </tag>
 <tag/>
```

and compare the results to see if this imethod is reliable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will definitely test this, I myself tried similar things (such as shortening my output) but this combination never occured to me.

Comment: Thank you, this works like a charm my 20+ hour select took only 47 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to change the column type in the table to be able to use XML queries, you can convert on the fly with XMLQuery or XMLTable.

One option is to use XMLTable to extract all of the relevant nodes, and count how many you get back:

```
select count(*)
from your_table
cross join xmltable(
  '//targetNodeName'
  passing xmltype(clobtype_column_withXMLs)
  columns dummy varchar2(1) path '@dummy'
);
```

The XMLTable produces one row for each matching node. As you are only counting them, and not using the contents of that node, I've used a dummy column name and contents, picking an attribute name that probably doesn't exist - if it might, change that to something else. The `dummy` value will therefore be null, but `count(*)` will count them anyway.

How that performs will have to be tested of course... it may well be even worse than using regular expressions. It would allow you to search for self-closed tags though, which might not matter to you based on what you're currently doing.

You could also adapt this to counts the nodes in each CLOB/XML value from your original table if that was useful; if it has an ID column for instance:

```
select t.id, count(*)
from your_table t
cross join xmltable(
  '//targetNodeName'
  passing xmltype(clobtype_column_withXMLs)
  columns dummy varchar2(1) path '@dummy'
)
group by t.id;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try this with a smaller sample size, this is something I was looking for, but I don't understand the last line (columns x xmltype path '.'), is this part of the XMLTABLE function?

Comment: @DragonTester yes; it's putting the `targetNodeName` node (use your own real name of course) into an XMLType column in the output called, for no particular reason, `x`. Usually you'd refer to that column in the select list, and even here a more descriptive name can be used; but as all you're doing is counting the rows output from XMLTable and ignoring the contents of the node it doesn't matter. I've only made it XMLType because I have no idea what it will contain - if it will fit in a `varchar2`.

Comment: @DragonTester - actually, that's probably going to use more resources than necessary; I've changed it to use a dummy value too, from a dummy attribute of the node. It's still ignored, but will use less memory.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the adjustment. Saving resources is key, it needs to be as fast as possible, and yes the contents of the nodes is irrelevant, I'm only interested of the quantity, the quantity itself is huge already (500 million was the max so far, but could be more in the future)

Comment: The method above works, but I will definitely test this when I have more time, I wonder if this is faster or not. Thanks!

Comment: I suspect it'll be slower than MarmiteBomber's approach, but I don't have data to test against. If you do try this it would be interesting to see how they compare, so do please report back.